# Flip camera upside down three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using PerspectiveCamera and OrbitControls and i am wondering if i could completely flip the camera so it’s basically upside down (making the scene apear upside down)? it would also be handy to know how to change it back again to the right way up!
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: FROM @WestLangley suggestion**

You only have to turn the camera upside down with this `camera.up.set(0, -1, 0);` after your camera definition.

```js
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);
    camera.up.set(0, -1, 0);
```

[image]

Just set it again to 0 whenever you want to restore to the regular position, so if you are thinking on flipping it based on any user interaction, I'd recommend to use a variable.

```js
//somewhere in your code
let flipped = true; //or false depending any user interaction assigned
camera.up.set(0, (flipped ? -1: 0), 0);
```

Comment: Try `camera.up.set( 0, - 1, 0 );` instead.

Comment: You're totally right @WestLangley, as usual... I'll modify it mentioning your suggestion

Comment: No matter what numbers I plug into `camera.up.set`, the results I'm seeing don't change at all. Am I missing something?